# Dep/Godep: define revision at package level

Tags: go, dependencies, dependency-management, godeps, govendor

In govendor was possible to specify which revision you wanted for each package of a dependency. For example:

> Repo "github.com/myorg/myrepo".
>
> Package "github.com/myorg/myrepo/x" with revision "16b65b2a4e3d30f47875b1cb2abc8a43fc"
>
> Package "github.com/myorg/myrepo/y" with revision "2190sdfds034e3d30f47875b1cb2a434c"

Code example:

```
{
    "checksumSHA1": "KP40Q38cB087cxh4TU1LWe1KOP4=",
    "path": "github.com/myorg/myrepo/x",
    "revision": "16b65b2a4e3d30f47875b1cb2abc8a43fc",
    "revisionTime": "2016-10-21T14:31:02Z"
},
{
    "checksumSHA1": "KP40Q38cB087cxh4TU1LWe1KOP4=",
    "path": "github.com/myorg/myrepo/y",
    "revision": "2190sdfds034e3d30f47875b1cb2a434c",
    "revisionTime": "2017-12-21T14:31:02Z"
},
```

Is this posible with Dep?

Thanks!

Comment: If you mean `go dep` then yes. Have a look at https://golang.github.io/dep/docs/Gopkg.toml.html#revision

Comment: There is explained how to set the revision at repo level (all packages of the repo would have the same revision). I would like to define the revision for each package.

Comment: Apologies, I misread the question. Unfortunately targeting different revisions of different packages in the same project is not supported. See https://github.com/golang/dep/issues/1208#issuecomment-331868812